# Double Submit CSRF protection cross domain

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, cookies

I'm confused as to how should I do CSRF protection. I have separate frontend (angularjs) and backend (Spring). They are deployed in completely separate places, and are communicating by REST.

My problem is as follows. Angular refuses to send my CSRF cookie cross domain - all I can send is CSRF header. I've tried adding `withCredentials` to both angular and CORS filter on my backend and setting up xsrf header and cookie as described [here under Usage](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Any ideas what could I be doing wrong? If you want some specific part of my code, please post and I'll deliver.

@Adding relevant code:

CORSFilter

```
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:9000");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with,origin,content-type,accept,X-XSRF-TOKEN, authorization, customer-id, X-AUTH-TOKEN");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "employee_name, employee_id, employee_customer_id, X-AUTH-TOKEN");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        if (request.getMethod()!="OPTIONS") {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        } else {
        }
    }
```

CSRF Filter

```
public class StatelessCSRFFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private static final String CSRF_TOKEN = "CSRF-TOKEN";
    private static final String X_CSRF_TOKEN = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";
    private final RequestMatcher requireCsrfProtectionMatcher = new DefaultRequiresCsrfMatcher();
    private final AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler = new AccessDeniedHandlerImpl();

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (requireCsrfProtectionMatcher.matches(request)) {
            final String csrfTokenValue = request.getHeader(X_CSRF_TOKEN);
            final Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

            String csrfCookieValue = null;
            if (cookies != null) {
                for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                    if (cookie.getName().equals(CSRF_TOKEN)) {
                        csrfCookieValue = cookie.getValue();
                    }
                }
            }
            if (csrfTokenValue == null || !csrfTokenValue.equals(csrfCookieValue)) {
                accessDeniedHandler.handle(request, response, new AccessDeniedException(
                        "Missing or non-matching CSRF-token"));
                return;
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    public static final class DefaultRequiresCsrfMatcher implements RequestMatcher {
        private final Pattern allowedMethods = Pattern.compile("^(GET|HEAD|TRACE|OPTIONS)$");

        @Override
        public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
            return !allowedMethods.matcher(request.getMethod()).matches();
        }
    }
```

app.js

```
(...)
$httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRF-TOKEN';
$httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'CSRF-TOKEN';
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('InterceptorCsrf');
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
(...)
```

InterceptorCsrf.js

```
angular.module('EnterprisePortalApp')
        .factory('InterceptorCsrf',function($cookies, $cookieStorage){
            function b(a){return a?(a^Math.random()*16>>a/4).toString(16):([1e16]+1e16).replace(/[01]/g,b)};
            return {
                //With each request generate new csrf token
                request: function(config) {
                    $cookieStorage.put("CSRF-TOKEN", b());
                    config.headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = $cookies.get('CSRF-TOKEN');
                    return config;
                }
            }   
});
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by saying that they are deployed in completely separate places? Is that on different servers?

Comment: @MicheleRicciardi Yup

Comment: Did you configure `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on your backend correctly? You may share code blocks related sections both backend and frontend sections. So people can inspect problems.

Comment: @İlkerKorkut I've added relevant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code blocks seems ok. Have you tried `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:9000"` change to this `*`.

BTW [it's a bug in chrome pointing localhost with its port](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67743) which won't fix([SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/deadly-cors-when-http-localhost-is-the-origin)).

Also you can try to give different domain names(instead of localhost you may use nginx proxy settings etc. it may be some tricky) both rest server and client-side hosts.

Extra Info according to that situation:

If using token based authentication for your REST service, you don't need to implement csrf protection additionally.

If user need to send his access token(eg. `jwt`) on every request for this rest service, your service is protected against csrf, and also similar method with csrf protection. `User gets token->request messages with token->decode token on backend->getuserid`(basic) and make his process the token based request process like these. In this scenario if user doesn't have token, he can't do anyhing.

Comment: I can't use `response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");` and `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:9000"` at the same time. ` A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true.` gets thrown

Comment: Do you use `X-AUTH-TOKEN` in every request? If so you don't need csrf token. BTW did you try to give specific domain to both front-end host and rest service host?

Comment: Would you explain why I don't need csrf token?

Comment: @KrzysztofPiszko If user need to send his access token(eg. jwt) on every request for this rest service, your service is protected against csrf, and also similar method with csrf protection. `User gets token->request messages with token->decode token on backend->getuserid and make his process` the token based request process like these. If you have this spec so don't waste your time to implement csrf protection, in this scenario if user doesn't have token, he can't do anyhing.

Comment: Got it, I didn't realize that it would be as simple as that. Now that I've reread what csrf is about it seems to fit. Thanks!

Comment: @KrzysztofPiszko I'm updating my answer with this extra information, please don't forget to give feedback if answer is useful for you.

Answer (score -1):

Working for me, with the following code

1. Server side, I have coded the [CSRF](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/#_csrf_protection) and [CORS](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/#_cors_negotiation) filters as described in the official [Spring Angular](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js) guide.
2. Client side, I had to code an *$http interceptor* as below, because AngularJS [doesn't automatically add](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#cross-site-request-forgery-xsrf-protection) the header for cross-domain requests.

   ```
   angular.module('appBoot')
     .factory('XSRFInterceptor', function ($cookies, $log) {

       var XSRFInterceptor = {

         request: function(config) {

           var token = $cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN');

           if (token) {
             config.headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = token;
             $log.info("X-XSRF-TOKEN: " + token);
           }

           return config;
         }
       };
       return XSRFInterceptor;
     });

   angular.module('appBoot', ['ngCookies', 'ngMessages', 'ui.bootstrap', 'vcRecaptcha'])
       .config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {

         $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
         $httpProvider.interceptors.push('XSRFInterceptor');

       }]);
   ```

Comment: I'm doing it by generating token on frontend, so it's not exactly like your method.